# Align bottom different size images

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have 5 images per slider, and all different sizes, I need a way to align all images to bottom so they are all aligned well, and being able to add the same padding between images.

The issue I am having is all the images bunch together, and padding isn't consistent between images.

```css
    ul.building_images {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 .building_images li {
 width: 270px;
 height: 270px;
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 margin: 2px;
 margin-right: -62px;
 /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
 position: relative;
 }

 .building_images li img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 }
 img {
 }

 .building_images li:hover img {
 /*width: 273px;*/
 height: 273px;
 /*background-color: blue;*/
 z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div id="randomContainer">
 <div class="container">    
     <div class="row">             
  <ul class="building_images">
  <li><img class="img1" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/1.png" />
   <div class="content_hidden1"><h3>Schools</h3>
      <p>Learning environments are about more than books, papers and grades. It is about keeping the students and teachers comfortable in the classroom while saving the school as much money as possible.
   </p></div>
  </li>
  <li><img class="img2" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/2.png" />
    <div class="content_hidden2"><h3>Commmercial</h3><p>Commercial buildings use over 60% of the electricity in the US, making energy efficiency more important than ever. Perfection has been an industry leader in providing energy efficient solutions while keeping comfort and serviceability in mind.</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/3.png" />
   <div class="content_hidden3"><h3>Civic</h3>
     <p>Whether a project for a courthouse, jail, police department or small office in City Hall, we know that we have to design the most functional, energy efficient solution for a tight budget.</p>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li><img class="img4" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/4.png" />
   <div class="content_hidden4"><h3>WAREHOUSE/LOGISTICS</h3>
      <p>Perfection designs and installs mechanical systems for warehouse and distribution facilities.
      <a href="/"><img src="">test</a>
      </p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><img class="img5" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/5.png" />
   <div class="content_hidden5"><h3>Health Care</h3>
     <p>Perfection understands the complexity of doing construction and maintenance services in an active health care facility. Communication, safety and proper project management are the keys to a successful outcome in this industry. 
  </p></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want the images to align at the bottom of your `li` elements (above the text) or do you want the images to stay above your text, but simply its bottom line should on the same height?

Comment: The text are only popouts on click of the images, I have those figured out just fine.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your question, and although I have created a jsfiddle example for you to try it out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO OF ANSWER](http://jsfiddle.net/oys8pfw9/3/)**

The images bunch together because of this css attribute:

```
.building_images li {
  margin-right: -62px;
}
```

By editing this value you can change the distance between each `li` element. Try for example `30px` for a constant `margin` between your `li`'s:

```
.building_images li { margin-right: 30px; }
```

---

Next you can position your images inside your `li` using the css tag `position: absolute`, which you already use to set `top: 0`. You can change this to `bottom: 0`.

Although you should prevent the images from stretching bigger than your slides are. I have done this adding `max-width: 100%` to your images.

Here is what your `.building_images li` could look like:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
.building_images li {
    width: 80px;     /* Set your width */
    height: 150px;   /* Set your height */
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0; /* Set your margins (top right bottom left) */
    list-style: none; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    background: red; /* Just for the demo, to see the <li> */
}
.building_images li img {
     max-width: 100% !important; /* Auto scale your images to full width */
     position: absolute; 
     top: auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0; /* Align your images at the bottom */
}
</style>
```

I have created minimized **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oys8pfw9/3/)** to show you the result of the two fixes named above.

Comment: That works great. Thank you for that. Now another curve ball. I have a hover option on the images here is the CSS, Some of the images resize on hover, and some dont. `.building_images li img:hover {
/*width: 273px;*/
max-width: 105% !important;
/*background-color: blue;*/
z-index: 1;
}`

Comment: Glad I helped. To solve your hover problem you need to understand the use of `max-width`. While `width: 100%` says "you HAVE to be full width", `max-width: 100%` says something like "you CAN be full width. If you are smaller, thats ok. Thats why smaller images do not get resized. I have created a fiddle for you to show the difference and create a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/oys8pfw9/5/
If you want to upscale your images replace every `max-width:` width `width`

Comment: Awesome, got it perfect, I was still able to accomplish it leaving max-width, I did a couple resizing on the images that weren't working with hover. Thank you so much for everything.